# Python sorting a list of lists ascending with 0 at the last place

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.x

Having, in Python 2.x

```
x = [
  [0,0,0],
  [1,2,3],
  [150,400,200],
  [0,0,0],
  [225,100,150]
]
```

What can I do to make it so x becomes

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [225,100,150],
  [150,400,200],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
]
```

ordered by `x[i][2]` ascending, with 0 last?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to custom order a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624323/python-how-to-custom-order-a-list)

Comment: @languitar didn't help, I need a general solution because that list of lists might have 3 fully zeroed elements, might have 1, might have none..

Comment: And what is the problem in these cases? Just use a lambda expression that selects the last entry of each sublist as the sorting key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be it:

```
sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[2] if x[2] > 0 else float('inf'))
```

Comment: This is it, I came across the float('inf') but I didn't manage to reach this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
x.sort(key=lambda y: (y[2] == 0, y[2]))
```