# Finding the highest value in a unique numbering system

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder containing test log folders. Each folder has the following format:

```
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.2.0.123
```

`TEST_BRANCH_TB` is exactly the same for every folder. The only part that changes is the number following (`1.2.0.123`). This counts up eg; `1.2.0.123` is followed by `1.2.0.124`. Atm my folder has the following subfolders;

```
 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.2.0.025
 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.010
 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.011
 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.012
 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014
 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017
```

**QUESTION:** How do I obtain the file paths of the latest two subfolders? in this case that would be the file path of  `TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017` and  `TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014`

EDIT: The subfolders are auto generated and I'm trying to automate another programme which requires the filepaths of the latest two subfolders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to custom order a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624323/python-how-to-custom-order-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a form of [natural sorting](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). You can do:

```
files='''\
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.2.0.025
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.010
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.011
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.012
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017'''

import re 

def nat(s):
    return tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))

print(sorted(files.splitlines(), key=nat))
```

Then just feed the files names from a `glob` to that sorting function.

---

Given these files:

```
$ ls TEST_BRANCH*
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.2.0.025 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.011 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014
TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.010 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.012 TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017
```

You can get a `glob` of them either with the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) or the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> list(Path(directory).glob('TEST_BRANCH_TB*'))
[PosixPath('/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.2.0.025'), PosixPath('/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.010'), PosixPath('/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.011'), PosixPath('/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.012'), PosixPath('/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014'), PosixPath('/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017')]
```

You can then sort that list of files with this function:

```
>>> sorted(map(str, Path(directory).glob('TEST_BRANCH_TB*')), key=nat)
['/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.2.0.025', '/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.010', '/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.011', '/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.012', '/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014', '/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017']
```

And get the last two:

```
>>> sorted(map(str, Path(directory).glob('TEST_BRANCH_TB*')), key=nat)[-2:]
['/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.014', '/tmp/TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.017']
```

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to python, how would I go about that @dawg?

Comment: name 'Path' is not defined -  I take it I'm missing the pathlib module?

Comment: add `from pathlib import Path`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

Directory here is where your folders are kept. eg "C:\ ...."

```
##For latest
    max(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/')), key=os.path.getmtime)
##For 2nd latest
import os; import glob
    sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/')), key=os.path.getmtime)[-2]
```

Comment: just says name 'directory' is not defined @Rahul Agarwal

Comment: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: malformed \N character escape

Comment: Ah ok. The program ran but it outputted the wrong folders

Comment: What was wrong ? Are they not the latest or random 2 folders?

Comment: yeah they were not the latest folders it had 1.3.0.010 and 1.2.0.025

Comment: Does the same on one containing 14 subfolders ranging from TEST_BRANCH_TB1.3.0.039 to TEST_BRANCH_TB1.5.0.012
It prints the latest 1.4 and the earliest 1.5