# How to sort a complex list with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

**Input list**

```
lst = [311, 409, 305, 104, 301, 204, 101, 306, 313, 202, 303, 410, 401, 105, 407, 408]
```

**Undesired output ( `lst.sort()` ):**

```
[101, 104, 105, 202, 204, 301, 303, 305, 306, 311, 313, 401, 407, 408, 409, 410]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[101, 301, 401, 202, 303, 104, 204, 105, 305, 306, 407, 408, 409, 410, 311, 313]
```

The last two digits are sorted ascending and the first digit is sorted ascending. I am unsure of how to approach this sort. I have tried using `lst.sort()` but that does not do the job. I have looked into other posts where they have implemented key but I have never used that before and I do not know how to implement that in this code.

Comment: please refrain from using list as variable name...its a keyword

Comment: @SarthakNegi `list` is not a keyword, it is a built-in function. Keywords in Python are for example `break` and `in`. Assigning to keywords will also throw an syntax error. Assigning to built-in functions will not, but since you override a built-in function it can bite you later when you want to use `list` as it was meant, and therefor indeed not recommended.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga my bad..thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is the output  `[101,301,401,202,303,104,204,105,305,306,407,408,409,410,311,313]`, you can use the following:

```
def my_key(x):
    return x%100, x/100


print(sorted(lst, key=my_key))
```

Or with a lambda function:

```
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x%100, x/100))
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: str(x)[1:] + str(x)[0])
```

Output:

```
[101, 301, 401, 202, 303, 104, 204, 105, 305, 306, 407, 408, 409, 410, 311, 313]
```

Also, as **@gdelab** correctly says, you could do it with divisions:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x % 100, x / 100))
```

#### Explanation

`str(x)[1:] + str(x)[0]` **creates a string** that starts with the last 2 digits (assuming your number always has 3 digits) and ends with the first digit. So it maps: 311 -> '113', etc., and so gets the numbers in the order you need.

Answer (score 0):

It appears a bit unclear what you are asking.  It sounds like your title's meaning is closer to "How to sort with a custom sorting order in Python?"

Here's my restatement of your question.  If it's wrong, then my answer will also be wrong.

```
I want to sort a list in a special way.  Each item is a three digit number and I want to sort by the last two digits, then by the first digit.  That is, I want to do something like this:

 > my_list=[311, 409, 305, 104, 301, 204, 101, 306, 313, 202, 303, 410, 401, 105, 407, 408]
 > my_list.sort()
 > print(my_list)
 [101,301,401,202,303,104,204,105,305,306,407,408,409,410,311,313]
```

That said, here are some ideas:

- This question might be relevant:  [Python: How to custom order a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624323/python-how-to-custom-order-a-list)?
- Custom sorting needs you to make a temporary value that sorts normally.  That is, you make an intermediate value for each input and sort the intermediate values.
- `(305 % 100)*10 + 305 // 100` equals `5*10+3` or `53`.
- Together, you get `print(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x % 100) * 10 + x // 100))`

Try to really grok why this works; similar problems are traditional homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

The pure Python solution is to sort first using the modulus (`%`) operator and then by the floor division (`//`) operator:

```
L = [311, 409, 305, 104, 301, 204, 101, 306, 313, 202, 303, 410, 401, 105, 407, 408]

res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (x % 100, x // 100))
```

For numeric data, a 3rd party library such as NumPy would support vectorised operations:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(L)

res = A[np.lexsort((A // 100, A % 100))]

array([101, 301, 401, 202, 303, 104, 204, 105, 305, 306, 407, 408, 409,
       410, 311, 313])
```