# Is it possible to sort a list of strings that represents Filipino numbers

Tags: python

list = [dalawa, tatlo, apat, siyam, isa] and is there a way to sort this to list = [isa, dalawa, tatlo, apat, siyam]. I an new in python so I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to custom order a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624323/python-how-to-custom-order-a-list)

Answer (score -1):

The python sort() method will sort a list in alphabetical order.
What you can do is assign the value of each filipino number as a dictionary, and then sort it according to value.

That should be done as so: (I'm making up the values)

```
list = {"dalawa":2, "tatlo":3, "apat":4, "siyam":5, "isa":1}

# look up lambda functions in order to better understand the below functionality. 
# In short what this does is, return to the sorted function the values of keys in the above dictionary and telling it to sort by them and not by the actual via resetting the key parameter to the lambda function.

result = sorted(list, key=lambda x:list[x[0]])
```

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea how to sort it according to its value and can it return only the key in the dictionary.